# Bug: useParams() hook initiates an error: TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, url-parameters

I'm trying to use the useParams() react hook to retrieve a parameter, but I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined`

This error is actually thrown by the hooks file, specifically this line (line 40):

```js
/modules/hooks.js:40

 39 | 
> 40 |   const match = useContext(Context).match;
 41 |   return match ? match.params : {};
 42 | }
```

My App.js file that contains the routing logic looks like this:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import theme from "./views/config/theme";
import { routes } from "./views/config/routes";
import Header from "./views/components/common/Header";
import Footer from "./views/components/common/Footer";

function App() {
return (
  <div>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route) => (
            <Route exact path={route.path}>
              {route.component()}
            </Route>
          ))}
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

The routes.js file that contains all the routes looks like this:

```js
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard";
import UserDetails from "../pages/UserDetails";

export const routes: [
{
  name: "Dashboard",
  path: "/dashboard",
  component: Dashboard,
  access: "public",
},
{
  name: "User details",
  path: "/user/:id",
  component: UserDetails,
  access: "private",
},
];
```

and this is the UsersDetails component file where I'm trying to use the useParams() hook, it looks like this:

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const UserDetails = () => {
const { id } = useParams();

return (
  <div>
    <p>{id}</p>
  </div>
);
};

export default UserDetails;
```

I'm using:

`NodeJS - 14.17.0`

and:

```json
"react": "^17.0.2"
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
"react-router": "^5.2.0"
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
"react-scripts": "4.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Setting Routes**

Firstly, in routes => component must be wrapped in open-close angle brackets. For example, my routes will look like this:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        name: "Dashboard",
        path: "/dashboard",
        component: <Dashboard />,
        access: "public",
    },
    {
        name: "User details",
        path: "/user/:id",
        component: <UserDetails />,
        access: "private",
    },
];
```

**2. Creating Two Components For Testing**

Next, I created two components like this:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  return <h2>Dashboard</h2>;
}

const UserDetails = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  return <div style={{ fontSize: "50px" }}>
    User Detail {id}
  </div>;
}
```

**3. Wrapping The App Component**

In App Component, we don't need to call component function (route.component() ), For example, look like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>

        <Header />

        <Switch>
          {routes?.map((route) => <Route path={route.path}>
            {route.component}
          </Route>)}
        </Switch>

      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, wrapping the components with < /> helped, and solved the problem

Comment: @AbdurahmanShiine welcome